# In how many points is tangent of $f(x)=\frac{e^x-2}{(e^x-1)^2}$ parallel with $y=x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

In how many points is tangent of $f(x)=\frac{e^x-2}{(e^x-1)^2}$ parallel with $y=x$

I found first derivative and put $$f'(x)=\frac{-e^x(e^x-3)}{(e^x-1)^3}=1$$

I can't solve it. I think that trick is only to find how many solutions are there, not finding exact ones.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $y=e^x$.

Then the equation symplifies to a polynomial equation of $-y(y-3)=(y-1)^3$.

**Hint2**:

You don't need to **solve** this equation, you only need to show how many solutions it has.

Comment: I have that, but can you solve it till the end?

Comment: @RushThaMan You don't need to solve it. You need to count the solutions. I suggest you first try to put it in the form $p(y)=0$, and then try plotting the polynomial $p$. How many zeroes does $p$ have?

Comment: Just to clarify: this is how many **positive** solutions the polynomial has; because $y=e^x>0$.

Comment: @MartinKochanski True.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility to show how many solutions an equation has, is to use the intermediate value theorem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

you know your function is continous and look for points where your new function $g(x):=f(x)-x$ is $>0$ and $<0$; intermediate value theorem says then there must be a solution.

Comment: IVT only tells you there is **a** solution and cannot actually be used for *counting* them.

Comment: Ok but in combination with monotony and discussion of bend you can use it.

Comment: Yes, you can. But your answer makes it look like IVT is *all* you need to count the zeroes, and this is simply not true.